# Speed the process of matching two columns using python

Tags: python, awk, intersect

If I have FILE1 like so:

```
1    56903
1    293943
1    320022
2    24050
2    404999
2    1003093
```

and FILE2 like so:

```
1    rs40209    56903
1    rs209485   79382
1    rs392392   320022
2    rs30302    504922
2    rs3202309  707899
2    rs39339    1003093
```

and I want to pull out the second column provided that the 1st and second of FILE1 match with FILE2, I can use a nested loop to read through FILE1 this awk command:

```
while read COL1 COL2; do

    awk -v COL1=$COL1  -v COL2=$COL2  '($1==COL1 && $3==COL2){print $2}' $FILE2

done < "$FILE1"
```

which would return

```
rs40209
rs392392
rs39339
```

as output.

However, using nested loops to do this is very very slow.

Most of the data are sorted, but not all, and I cannot sort because other files depend on these files being in the current order.

Using python, what would be a very fast way to get this done for FILE1 with ~2M entries and FILE2 with ~1M entries?

Comment: isn't `rs392392` also a valid one?

Comment: yes. edited to reflect this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python you would read the contents of 1st file in a `set`. The `set` is backed by a hash table which average `O(1)` (constant-time) lookup:

```
with open('FILE1') as file:
    file1_contents = { tuple(line.split()) for line in file }
```

Then filter the second file:

```
with open('FILE2') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        c1, c2, c3 = line.split()
        if (c1, c3) in file1_contents:
            print(c2)
```

Which with `FILE1` and `FILE2` having contents as in the question, results in output

```
rs40209
rs392392
rs39339
```

With 2 million entries, the set will consume quite a bit amount of ram (closer to 1 gigabyte), but will have the fastest asymptotic time complexity. Total time for 2 million entries in FILE1 and 1 million in FILE2 was 5 seconds on my laptop. It also is ~4 times faster than Fabricator's AWK script:

```
% time awk -f script.awk FILE2 > /dev/null
awk -f script.awk FILE2 > /dev/null  17.47s user 0.14s system 99% cpu 17.606 total
% time python filter.py > /dev/null     
python filter.py > /dev/null  4.32s user 0.20s system 99% cpu 4.526 total
```

Comment: Based on your response it seems that not importing or especially recent version of python is necessary? Thank you very much this was quite instructive.

Comment: 2.7 is required for `{ tuple(line.split()) for line in file }`, syntax for 2.6 is `set(tuple(line.split()) for line in file)`

Answer (score 1):

awk has associative array, and the first file can be loaded in the beginning:

script.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    while (( getline < "file1.txt" ) > 0) {
        file1[$1 " " $2] = 1;
    }
}

{
    if ($1 " " $3 in file1) {
        print $2;
    }
}
```

Then run

```
awk -f script.awk file2.txt
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you help me understand why this will be significantly faster?

Comment: I ran this and it is in fact incredibly fast; near as I can tell the speed up is on the order of ~10000x. If anyone can help me understand why this is so I would be appreciative.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly awk's associative array is implemented, but lookup should be a O(log(N)) operation where N is the number of rows for file1, we need to do it for all M rows in file2, so O(M*log(N)) altogether. On other hand, your original solution is O(M*N).